# Setup and configure Zend Skeleton Application

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend Framework 2 and have installed the Skeleton Application manually. My application is kept in "D:\xampp\htdocs\zf2". I've created a virtual host but when I point it to the public folder in D:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\public" it gives the error `object not found`. However, if I have the option other option like "D:\xampp\htdocs\zf2" then it works. I've also tried putting index.php at the end and that also works but it gives output like this.

[image]

I've set the virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public"
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public">
        #DirectoryIndex index.php

        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts file I added the line `127.0.0.1 zf2`

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Please add the _exact_ vhost configuration in the question.

Comment: there is problem in loading the css and js files that's it is showing such. there is no error.

Comment: but when i acces it throuh localhost i-e:- localhost/zf2/public then it shows the zkeletonapplication in the right way.

Comment: Shouldn't it be... `DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public"`, without the file? The same with `<Directory>`.

Comment: yes you are right raina77ow it should be D:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public, and now it is showing me in the right way, thanks to all